# Website can't be reached

Tags: pi-4

I am trying to reach a bunch of websites (eg: github.com) and I receive the message 'This site can't be reached'.
I figure this might be a problem of networks in the rpi since I can access the websites on other computers.
How can I solve this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:a3:ae:c6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 501  bytes 47256 (46.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 501  bytes 47256 (46.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2001:8a0:ec90:f100:740f:b24e:27d4:7d53  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::9967:67b:5a73:8696  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:a3:ae:c7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4316  bytes 1223865 (1.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1892  bytes 247899 (242.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Is the network on the Pi up and running? Can you ping local machines? And what does e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8` return? Please update your question with relevant information

Comment: It returns 'From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=x Destination Host Unreachable'

Comment: How do you send requests to these websites?

Answer (score 1):

This clearly is a network issue, and not so much specifically for the Pi.

Anyway, a quick fault-searching would be:

First check is the routing table. Use `netstat -rn`. It will probably give you something like :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

If there is no destination 0.0.0.0, you must add it by hand:

```
sudo route add -net default gw 192.168.1.1
```

and check your DHCP server (which is probably on your internet router).

Next step would be to ping the gateway:

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
```

If the router is not pinagble, your Wifi connection is probably down and you may need to check the WiFi.

If the router is the default gateway, the router is pingable, but you still cannot access the Internet, then your router is the problem.

Comment: I did that and this was the output: ping -c3 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 106ms
pipe 3

Comment: So, if your default gateway from netstat is indeed 192.168.1.1, you have, as I wrote a WiFi problem.

Comment: But isn't it weird that everything works properly in every other device I use?

Comment: If you misconfigured your pi (e.g. a type in the wifi key), then this is exactly the kind of problems you will see. So, no, it is not weird, it is to be expected. You probably misconfigured Wifi, and a misconfiguration on your Pi will not affect your other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you plugged in the Raspberry PI to an ethernet cable correctly? You can check the connection by plugging in a laptop instead and trying to access the internet over the same cable. Make sure it works, else something is wrong with the Raspberry's configuration. 
Please check that you have connected to the internet correctly and that it has a local IP (e.g. 192.168.0.123)

This can be done with `ifconfig` in Linux.

Comment: I am using wireless connection that seems to work with google.com or even facebook.com

Comment: Can you please check your DNS server then? If you can only access certain domains it probably has something to do with that.

Comment: By accessing the dhcpcd.conf ?